# How to count words in array that start with a capital letter

Tags: ruby, string, capitalization

I'm working on an array containing Twitter handles such as:

```
array = ["@user1","@User2","@uSer3","@User4"]
```

I want to know how many handles start with a capital letter.

Comment: "I would like to know how to access the first letter of each string in the array." – The first letter of each string is always `@` in your case, so you don't really need to access it, you already know what it is.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sure it's the first character, but I'm not sure `@` would be considered a letter.

Comment: @SagarPandya in the context of programming, anything that has a mapping in any of the character sets is a character. That includes the different alphabets, numbers, symbols and special characters without glyph like the whitespace. So, yes, the first character of any string in that array is @.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a regex to match `@` followed by a capital letter at the start of the string.

`count` is the most semantic function *(thanks to @crenmo)*:

```
array.count {|e| e =~ /^@[A-Z]/}
```

`select` is useful if you'd like a list of matched elements:

```
array.select {|e| e =~ /^@[A-Z]/ }
```

Use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` if you wish to match non-English uppercase letters *(thanks to @CarySwoveland)*.

For reference, indexing into a string can be done with bracket notation (although I didn't wind up using this): `str[0]`

Comment: `inject` is overused. Both `Array` and `Enumerable` have an instance method called `count` which do what OP asks for - counting something.

Comment: Works perfectly, I even understand what you did there with the ternary but why the 0 inside the inject ?

Comment: Consider changing your last line to `array.count { |s| s.match? /\A@[[:upper:]]/ }`. `\A` is the beginning-of-string anchor whereas `^` is the beginning-of-line anchor. Both work here, but `\A` is what you mean. `[[:upper:]]` (or `\p{Upper}`) matches uppercase Unicode letters (in order to match "Éclair", for example). (For the docs, search for those expressions in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html)).

Comment: @CarySwoveland After thinking about it more, you're right: including `inject` in the answer adds nothing to `count` and detracts from the overall usefulness of the answer. I'm removing it, but keeping `select` because I think it's useful for obtaining matched elements in addition to a raw count, which is often the case.

Comment: No need for the attribution in your answer (though I know that's quite common here at SO). My preference is to put that in comments, if desired. More generally, I look at answers like passages of a book, concise and focused, always with the reader in mind. Text in books may go through several iterations before the presses are switched on, some of the changes having been prompted by suggestions from reviewers.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is "how many in a collection" , then [count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) could very well be the way to go.
The regular expression `/[[:upper:]]/`  has the benefit that it matches capital letters other than A-Z.

```
array = ["@user1","@User2","@uSer3","@User4"]
p array.count{|handle| handle[1].match?( /[[:upper:]]/ )}  # => 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though there's an accepted answer, I felt like it's worth mentioning that the same can be accomplished using `#count` instead of `#inject`:

```
array = ["@user1","@User2","@uSer3","@User4"]

capital_letters = ('A'..'Z')

array.count {|x| capital_letters.include?(x[1])}
#=> 2
```

If a block is given to the `#count` method, it counts the number of elements for which the block returns a true value. The block, in this case, evaluates to true if the second letter of the array `x[1]` is a capital letter from A to Z. This works under the assumption that every string in the array starts with a `"@"`.

Comment: @ggorlen I agree a regex might be a better option, the main reason I choose this version is because the question also asks for a way to access parts of a string so I tried to add something else to the answer that might be useful. Thank you for bringing that up

Comment: @Виктор You will want to create the range outside of the block in order to avoid generating multiple of the same range, one for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @mwp Looking at the [source](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) for `range.include?`, it looks like it's O(1) because it detects that these are ASCII chars and can do a quick greater than/less than. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @mwp That's definitely a better approach, thank you both for improving the answer

Comment: I'm wondering if `('A'..'Z')` is O(1) as well. Ruby might not generate the whole range item by item but may simply populate the start and end points and leave its state like that until a full expansion is required (which it isn't in `include?`). I'm not 100% sure about this, though; might have time to dig into the source a bit.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, it's O(1). The expression creates an instance of the Range class with a start of 'A' and an end of 'Z'.  It doesn't do any enumeration at the time of creation. And `include?` _will_ enumerate through the range if the start/end/character to match are not simple values.

Comment: Yup, we're on the same page. I learned something new--go Ruby. I'll tap an upvote on this A, might even be faster than the regex.